# Count the rising edges in a 128 wide bitfield

Tags: assembly, 8051

Number of rising edges = The number of "01" bit patterns.
I do not know how to copy only 1 or two bits from a long pattern in a register, after that I thought about doing shift and compare it to "01" and increase R5 (which is the output, contains the number of rising edges)
My input is R7 (Base address of the 128-bit bitfield in the internal memory)

```
COUNT_01_NOMOD:

; [TODO: Place your code here]
    MOV R6, @R7
    back: SHL $1, R6
        CJNE R6, 1, cero_first
        cero_first: CJNE, 0, back
    INC R5
    


    RET
```

Comment: You need an algorithm, so work on that first, then the assembly code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. What should that algorithm do?

Comment: The algorithm should produce the answer you want.  If you can do that in C, then you can implement it in asm.  At least for the basics of detecting `01` at the bottom of a byte, then counting `01`s in a byte.  (BTW, that's a falling edge if you iterate from low bit to high bit.)  Where you need to deal with integers wider than registers or even a C `uint64_t`, you probably want to think in asm about how to handle the boundary between bytes, where one byte could have a high `1` and the next could have a low `0`.  You could use flags maybe, or shift a bit across bytes, or whatever.

Comment: Does it work to do `popcount( x ^ (x>>1) )`?  No, that produces a `1` for `10` as well.  Maybe `(~x>>1) & x` and popcount, looping over the set bits and counting iterations, or just shifting them all out one at a time and adding the carry flag to an accumulator.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74786830/471129) answer to get some ideas. It uses a bit queue of 12 bits in width as a buffer to feed in a byte at a time (8-bits) and feed out 5-bit codes, regardless of when/where they cross byte boundaries. You could use something like that to feed in 8-bit bytes ensuring there are always at least 2 bits in the bit queue, and remove 1 bit at a time, while looking at the 2 lowest bits each iteration.  The discussion about how the bytes fit together is relevant too, since you'll also be looking at the last bit of one byte and the first bit of another.

Comment: I'm sure there's also many other  ways to approach the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. SO is not a code providing service, and not a forum. You might want to read "[ask]". -- Probably you need to learn the difference between developing an algorithm (which commonly is independent of the programming language) and its implementation. Both are parts of the development process. You cannot start solving such tasks by typing source code. Therefore, think about an algorithm, [edit] your question to present it, and add where in design and/or implementation you stumble.

Comment: Your algorithm will more than likely need to handle the following: 1) be able to correctly count the sequence `001` as a single rising edge (in other words don't just rotate in 2 bits at a time), 2) manage the cases where the lowest bit of a byte is 0 and the highest bit of the next byte is 1, and most importantly 3) *know when to stop!*